# What do never malloc'd chunks look like in glibc malloc?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, glibc

I had assumed that `glibc` would treat the never allocated chunk of the heap as if it was `free()`d, populating it with pointers for the free list.  So that, if the initial unallocated heap is 0x1000 bytes, and `malloc` allocates the first 0x400, we'd see a second chunk beginning at 0x400 with `fd` and `bk` pointers.

However, experimentation suggests that this is *not* true, and that the never allocated chunk does not have pointers.

1. Is that correct?
2. If so, how does `malloc` keep track of it, its size, and know when to take from it and when not to?
3. Is this the same thing as the wilderness chunk?